# How do I store the result as cache in C#

Tags: c#

So I have below code running, where I am calling an Api, which gives me result a Json Array which I am later querying in my code. The response, I get from the api is mostly constant and since it has SOME data, it takes few seconds to get the complete result. I would like to know, if I can store the result coming from api in some way in cache in order to make the whole processing part faster?

EDIT: below code is inside a Foreach loop

```
foreach (var did in myDeserializedClass)
 {
  if (did.id == matchedid)
   {
     url = "https://.../api/information/test";
     var response = await Request(Stream.Null, url, "GET");
     string message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     var allcodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoCode>>(message);
     foreach(var cc in allcodes )
    {....// rest of my code
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cache"? Where do you think it's inefficient, as in the data is loaded again? I mean, with what you show objects will just contain the data until they go out of scope and get collected by the GC.

Comment: It's cached in `allcodes` already. If you want to use it somewhere else, widen the scope of the variable. If you want to use it tomorrow, write the json to a text file and deserialize it from the text file tomorrow

Comment: thats right, i want to store it when it is called again, as the response from api call will mostly remain constant. oh I forgot to mention, the api call is inside a foreach loop

Comment: When you say you want to store the result in cache to make the whole processing part faster, what exactly do you mean? Are you not intending to make further calls?

Comment: Are you actually looking to cache this for a period (potentially reusing a stale result) or do you just want to debounce multiple requests?

Comment: I edited the question , The api call is inside a for each loop and I would not like to call api each time condition is matched. I would like to store the result in memory cache for next time condition is matched, and do my further querying

Comment: Do you mean the next time during one run through the loop, or the next time as in the next time the code that contains the loop is called?

Comment: next time the code contains the loop

Comment: How long do you intend to cache it for? A set period of time or indefinitely?

Comment: How long can I cache it for? The code is intended to be called multiple times in a day, lets make it indefinite for now

Comment: I'd suggest looking at T Neilsen's answer in that case. You could just set a very long expiry, I imagine.

Comment: You're making this very complicated. Write `message` to a text file with the single line of code `File.WriteAllText`. When you want to use it, read the file with `File.ReadAllText` outside a loop, deser it to `allcodes` outside a loop. Loop and hit `allcodes` many times. If you want you can also put a logic to check the LastModified date of the file with `File.GetLastWriteTime` just before you read it and if it's more than 1 day ago, call the api again and overwrite `message` to the file again, thereby renewing the file date for another day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use a memory cache, even Microsoft provide one which if possible also can be place in the api side for quicker lookups

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0